# Proving that $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I was given the hint of using the Mean Value Theorem. I've gone over the definitions but am having a hard time seeing what to do.

Comment: Its derivative is bounded on $[1,\infty)$, therefore it is Lipschitz continuous, which implies uniform continuity.

Comment: apply the MVT $\,\,$